# AWS CLI: RDS snapshots filtered by type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

Trying to return a list of all RDS snapshots whose type is manual. I thought it'd be one of the following, but neither is working.

Column header is Type, tried this;

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].{Snapshot:Snapshot}' --filters Name=Type,Values=manual --output text
```

AWS documentation says the name may actually be SnapshotType;

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].{Snapshot:Snapshot}' --filters Name=SnapshotType,Values=manual --output text
```

Both are returning a variation of

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeDBSnapshots operation: Unrecognized filter name: SnapshotType

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First, per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html), filters is not a supported parameter of this command:

> --filters (list)
>
> This parameter is not currently supported.

Second, that query syntax is invalid for the response, because the list is named "DBSnapshots", not "Snapshots". The example query below will filter the list to only return snapshots where SnapshotType is "manual".

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --query "DBSnapshots[? SnapshotType=='manual']"
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Comment: Completely missed the lack of filter, thanks for pointing that out. And thanks for the answer, worked like a charm!

Comment: How to do the same with boto3 sdk?

Comment: now aws cli has the option directly `aws rds describe-db-snapshots  --snapshot-type manual`